# EditText output won't return a decimal (Beginner Q)

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, decimal

I've an input "L2" which is input into an EditText field with inputType "numberDecimal". I click a button and want that number to display in a different EditText field also with inputType "numberDecimal". My issue is that when i input a decimal in L2, such as 1.536, the output becomes rounded to the nearest integer (2 in this case). I would like the output to be exactly same as the input. Below is a snippet of my code. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    final DecimalFormat d = new DecimalFormat("#");
    double xx2 = 0;

    final EditText Lq2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.L2);

    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
      @Override
    public void onClick(View v){

    double xx2 = Double.valueOf(Lq2.getText().toString());

    Rq2.setText(d.format(xx2));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@j w Russell,
//use this

 final DecimalFormat d = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont convert the value to the double convert it to the float

```
float xx2 =  Float.valueOf(Lq2.getText().toString());
Rq2.setText(d.format(xx2));
```